# SAP Spartacus Translations

Tags: angular9, spartacus-storefront

Is there a possibility disable SAP Spartacus I18next module in order to use my own translation module/strategy? 
I'm trying to use my own shared module with translations but it is based on i18next library same as inspartacus/core, it seems like they are conflicting, because separately they work good.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but it would require a lot of work. `I18nModule` is a core part of the project and is imported in the `StorefrontFoundationModule` that is used in the in the `StoreFrontModule` and so on.

Therefore, to remove it would require to import all of the modules imported in the `StorefrontFoundationModule`, `StoreFrontModule` and `B2cStorefrontModule`. Directly to your `AppModule`. This is doable but the app is likely not to work.

Many components and services depend on translations so you would need to make sure your custom translation is provided in a way that it satisfies those dependencies.

Basically I am saying you are better of trying to extend or override the Spartacus translation functionalities to fit your use case. This module is configurable, extendable and powerful. Feel free too take a look at our documentation on the subject https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/i18n/#page-title.

Comment: Thank you!! Very useful info. Maybe you know the propper way to work with state (NgRX) in spartacus (how to use or extend it), because this part is not documented at all. I can create my own store but is it right way?

Comment: (1/3) Yes I am familiar with how to do it.

By default the NgRx layer in Spartacus is abstracted by a layer of "facade services" that expose methods to interact with the store. We recommend using those to communicate with the store since it allows easier maintainability for us.

Comment: (2/3) If you wish to extend the store there are different ways to go about it based on your needs. The first step would be to start by adding effects that reuse the existing
actions. This way can be used to integrate custom behavior in the flow of events. If you want to go further, you can add your own state "slice" like shown in this example
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus-bootcamp/tree/master/src/app/features/state. This will allow you to save an entirely new data.

Comment: (3/3) One last general item of note (might not apply to this use case). If you need to load custom data, you are free on how you do it. That said, involving NgRx does bring about some complexity. Therefore, if the data is shared between multiple components/services there is value in involving the store. If not, you could use a singleton service.

Comment: I try to extend I18nextTranslationService, but faced with an issue that I18NEXT_INSTANCE is not exported in i18n module. And as well in sources I see some comments that it's critical to have a single instance cause of some bug fix. Can you recoment what normally should I do?